# Swift string and integer subscripts

Tags: swift, string, swift4

This is rather a theoretical question

why the following (and more in analogy) is not a part of the Swift standard library? What would be *bad cases*?

```
extension String {
    subscript(_ range: Range<Int>) -> Substring {
        return self[index(startIndex, offsetBy: range.lowerBound)..<index(startIndex, offsetBy: range.upperBound)]
    }
}

extension Substring {
    subscript(_ range: Range<Int>) -> Substring {
        return self[index(startIndex, offsetBy: range.lowerBound)..<index(startIndex, offsetBy: range.upperBound)]
    }
}
```

Comment: You're hiding an O(n) operation behind an O(1) looking subscript.

Comment: @hamish so as I say in my comment to the answer below - the reason is keeping subscript complexity obvious, right?

Answer (score 10):

To expand on Hamish's point, this would have very surprising behavior. Let's consider the simpler (but equivalent) case of `string[int]`, which this would build on. Why not subscript strings by ints.

Strings are collections of *characters*, not bytes. They can be stored in UTF-8, which means that you don't know how big a character is, and you can't just jump to arbitrary places. In order to figure out "character 100" you have to start at the beginning and decode everything. That's O(n).

So you write code like this, that feels very "safe":

```
for index in 0..<string.count {
    print(string[index])
}
```

But secretly this is O(n^2) which is really surprising because it sure looks like O(n). You might say "well, my string is only 20 characters long, so who cares," but we use strings for lots of things, including multi-megabyte `NSTextStorage`. (And this expands dramatically in Swift versus some other languages because Swift includes generic algorithms whose performance promises rely on the fact that subscripting is O(1).)

So I can make things "easy" for you, until suddenly things get really hard when you care even the least little bit about performance. (And I don't mean "performance" as in "super fast." I mean "performance" as in "doesn't grind the entire app to a halt for minutes.)

Languages with "simple" indexing are "simple" because they ignore Unicode. So everything is great until you get fed an emoji and it all explodes and you have to write crazy nasty code to work around it. Swift decided that things like emoji (and Chinese, and Arabic, and Thai, and...) are very normal things to put in a string, and so should be dealt with as first-class, rather than worked around when things explode.

If you want to study a language that went the other way, look at Go, which has a "rune" system for strings that is very hard to get right the moment an emoji shows up. The Go answer is "programers should just do the right thing when there might be multibyte characters." Swift's answer is "the language should always do the right thing." There are legitimate arguments for both, but Swift's approach avoids a lot of real-world bugs (like the horrible security problem I introduced for my Chinese users when I accidentally truncated multibyte passwords when working in ObjC).

Comment: Brilliant answer useful for generations... and I mean it! I know pretty well how Unicode storage works. I know that bytesof(subtring(x, n, m)) is expensive. Still substring operations are common and `str[index(startIndex, offsetBy: range.lowerBound)..<index(startIndex, offsetBy: range.upperBound)] is a bit cumbersome. Is the main reason why integer subscripts are not provided just a obviousness of complexity? ("yes" I consider to be a good answer)

Comment: What you say about "programmers" vs "language" is very true... on the other hand... Swift is puristic - and may end up with a widely used pod named like  "SmartString" used by many... and providing all that "bad" stuff. 

One might say - this is not a language fault... on the other hand, when there is some inferred complexity, people will seek simple solutions. This is an issue of language design.

I do not have a good solution... like warning "you are using potentially expensive subscript, silence it with parentheses"? ;)

Comment: I've often considered creating the type you mean, but it's proper name is "DumbString." Generally if you're slicing a string you're either (a) doing something wrong (because it won't localize), or (b) writing a parser. I'm often doing (b). So what I actually want is a simpler way to convert between `Data` and literal strings. In `Data` form, bytes are bytes, so your intuitions hold up. And yeah, from the discussion from the stdlib folks, it seems to just be the fact that subscript promises O(1), and they can't provide that.

Comment: The problem with "silence it with parentheses" is that you may not be using the subscript directly. It may be part of a generic algorithm. Since strings are Collections, functions like `first(where:)` and `joined()` might be generic. How does the compiler warn you that these are O(n^2) (or worse)? And how would you silence it? Instead you should generally be asking yourself "why am I slicing by integers?" If it's not "because I'm writing a parser of fixed-length format" ask yourself if this is really the right tool vs. creating a specialized extension method that does what you mean.

Comment: But yeah, I'm often writing parsers of fixed-length formats, so yeah, I feel the pain. And we need some better helper methods. Airspeed Velocity just suggested the creation of a `.midpoint` property for instance. https://twitter.com/AirspeedSwift/status/906892260205146113

Comment: "Parentheses" was more a joke then anything else :) But you got the point. The most annoying part is just fiddling with indexes doing small jobs like format 1234567890 -> 123-456-7890 etc. But I'd conclude that the O(1) promise is more important then programmer's laziness.

Comment: And what we really need is an integrated regex engine that would handle this much more powerfully without the danger of crashing when the string is the wrong length. I've heard the stdlib team mention that several times.

Comment: Oh sure, regexp with some decent syntax sugar.